# How can I know my Stopwatch has run?

Tags: guava

I use several stopwatches in my application. They are all created together, but only some of them have actually run (due to exceptions earlier in the code or other things).

After my application has run, I'm creating my report using those stopwatches. For instance, I'm doing the following:

```
Stopwatch subStopwatch = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
Stopwatch mainStopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
try {
  // do something 1
  subStopwatch.start();
  // do something 2
  subStopwatch.stop();
} finally {
  mainStopwatch.stop();
  System.out.printf("Total run time: %s%n",  mainStopwatch);
  if (!subStopwatch.isRunning()) {
    System.out.printf("  including sub run time: %s%n", subStopwatch);
  }
}
```

The problem in this code is that if something happens in "do something 1" (return, exception), subStopwatch will be printed anyways.

The following solutions work:
- Using a boolean to indicate I started the stopwatch.
- Using a stopwatch more locally and using a report mechanism that contains the information I'm looking for.

But the main question remains: can I know that a stopwatch has run using Stopwatch only.

Comment: Why not put the two "do something"s in different `try` blocks, and put the stopwatch *around* the second `try` instead of inside it?

Comment: Because if it fails I don't care about the sub run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [elapsed time](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html#elapsed%28java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) on the stopwatch:

```
if (subStopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) > 0) {
    // it ran
}
```

Comment: I'll actually use `subStopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) > 0 && !subStopwatch.isRunning()` to check that it has run and it's not because of an issue. Thanks!